# Можно ли создать чат для терминала linux в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, консоль, tor

Хочу попробовать сделать простенький чат для общения нескольких людей в консоли)

Но проблема в том, что даже не знаю с чего начать. Писать собираюсь на `python`, но с проходом трафика через `tor`. Как такое реализовать в linux?

Comment: Уже написан `man talk`. Если же вы про глобальную сеть, то он назвается `irssi`.

Answer (score 5):

Разделите задачу на несколько подзадач - изучить сокеты tcp/udp для связи (хотя может это будет чат через http, но это вряд ли). Можно найти любой пример чата. Вот к примеру, люби пытаются - [en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342336/simple-chat-udp-client-and-server-using-python-cant-use-str-as-send-pa) или вот [github](https://github.com/Ayanjit/python-UDP-Chat).

Второе - найдите подходящую библиотеку для UI в консоле (что бы упросить себе жизнь), например, [ncurse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

В принципе, если делать без регистрации, на udp, то вполне легко можно сделать за пару вечеров.

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю над этим)